# How do I install Python(x,y) for linux (Elementary OS)?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, package

I'm kinda noob in Linux, and in my class they asked us to install `Python(x,y)` but I've just recently moved from Windows to Linux. So I read this webpage and followed the steps: https://launchpad.net/~pythonxy/+archive/ubuntu/pythonxy-stable

But then I saw many tutorials on how to install Linux packages and they told that to install a Linux package (ppa) after adding the package to my system and updating it I had to use the next command line:

```
sudo apt install "name of package"
```

The problem is that I don't know the name of the package for `Python(x,y)` and I can't find it any where. Does someone knows the name of the package or knows an alternative way to install it. I'm using Elementary OS.

Comment: You need ti add the PPA to yiur liist if software sources, then searcxh for a package named pythonxy or python-xy in your package manager.

Comment: The list of package names is on the page you linked to, under "Overview of published packages".

Comment: IIRC Python(x, y) is just a collection of science-oriented Python packages that would be a mess to install manually on Windows. On Linux you can just install the packages you need (most probably python, ipython, numpy, scipy, spyder) through the package manager.

Comment: The package names are on that page... *Overview of published packages*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing in through PPAs, install it with `sudo apt install python-xy-meta-current`.